# How can certain python libraries be imported in azure ML?Like the line import humanfriendly gives error

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

In execute python module. The line

```
import humanfriendly
```

gives error.
How to fix this?

Comment: What error did you get? Please update your error details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is not clear, I don't know what happended when you got error via `import humanfriendly` as you said. So I just can do for you that only post my steps about how to install `humanfriendly` Python package in Azure ML, as below.

1. According to the section [`Technical Notes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/cdb56f95-7f4c-404d-bde7-5bb972e6f232/#Anchor_3) of the document "Execute Python Script", I download the `humanfriendly` package from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanfriendly). I decompressed the package (the same for either [`.whl`](https://pypi.python.org/packages/8e/24/de8e894b8f27d726e10af64123f1de64fe13cb106b281965419d004feabf/humanfriendly-3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=9a1a8389e398de5170bc68c0917d94ca) file or [`.tar.gz`](https://pypi.python.org/packages/e3/98/5de3e2f2d9dad8d9709be88c1bb930c1ea91f84bea9b85b7c04d52104bd8/humanfriendly-3.2.tar.gz#md5=a8176d0c4e7e58505844c53b748a82da) file), and package its `humanfriendly` directory as a zip file.
2. Then I click the botton `+New` and select the `DATASET` tab to Upload a new dataset from a local file, as the figures below.

   Fig 1. Click the botton `+New`
   [image]
   Fig 2. Select the tab `DATASET`
   [image]
   Fig 3. Upload a new dataset from a local file
   [image]
3. Drag & drop the dataset module `humanfriendly.zip` and a `Execute Python Script` module to connect them and write the Python code, as below.

[image]

Here is My testing code in the `Execute Python Script`.

```
import humanfriendly

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    user_input = '16G'
    num_bytes = humanfriendly.parse_size(user_input)
    print num_bytes
```

Finally, I ran the experiment successfully.

---

Update: The file structure tree of my `humanfriendly` zip. I decompressed the wheel file and just package the `humanfriendly` directory.

```
humanfriendly
├── data.csv
└── humanfriendly
    ├── cli.py
    ├── compat.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── prompts.py
    ├── sphinx.py
    ├── tables.py
    ├── terminal.py
    ├── tests.py
    ├── text.py
    └── usage.py
```

Comment: Thank you Peter. I followed the same steps,compressed a .whl,.tar.gz and another .csv file . Import humanfriendly gives error ,0085,no module named humanfriendly.

Comment: @SameekshaGupta Please see the update content of my post.