# How import 'html5lib' package to Python 3.5 Script in Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: python, python-import, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to import the package `html5lib` to `Azure Machine Learning`, into a `Execute Python Script` module. It's a similar question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593469/how-can-certain-python-libraries-be-imported-in-azure-mllike-the-line-import-hu), but same solution didn't work... :/

My steps until now:

1. I got the latest version of `HTML5LIB` package from the [project website](https://pypi.org/project/html5lib/);
2. Unzip tar.gz file and re-zip as .ZIP file;
3. Upload the file in Azure Studio as a Dataset named as 'html5lib.zip';
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3UvI.png)
4. Add the zip file as dataset into my Experiment and connected to Script Bundle Input;
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thDfa.png)
5. Run the following script:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cj91.png)

Then, I got the error:

```
Error 0085: The following error occurred during script evaluation, please view the output log for more information:
---------- Start of error message from Python interpreter ----------
Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 189, in batch
mod = import_module(moduleName)
File "C:\pyhome\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\temp\6d718116a1f549e59a5b96c5d6360911.py", line 22, in <module>
import html5lib
ImportError: No module named 'html5lib'
Process returned with non-zero exit code 1
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Ran the following commands on windows command line.

```
mkdir html5lib
# cd into above directory
pip install html5lib --target=.
# Zip the contents of the directory html5lib.zip
```

This is code in Python Script Module

[image: This is code in Python Script Module]

This is screenshot of the experiment and success message after executing the experiment

[image: This is screenshot of the experiment and success message after executing the experiment]